# What is that yellow fixture that the launch vehicle is resting on?

Tags: launch, identify-this-object, launch-vehicle, vehicle-assembly-building

What is that fixture called as? I think it is used to support the launch vehicle during integration. Please correct if wrong.
source - https://www.ruaviation.com/news/2019/3/12/13107/?h
[image]

[image]
here's another one showing many such structures.
source - https://spaceflightnow.com/2021/01/10/china-to-begin-construction-of-space-station-this-year/

Comment: Which yellow fixture? There are more than one.

Comment: The one that the launch vehicle is resting on.

Comment: Can you credit the source of the image? See the first few images here as well https://www.roscosmos.ru/467/ and the image here https://www.ruaviation.com/news/2019/3/12/13107/?h and some of these also https://www.roscosmos.ru/26191/

Comment: I'd call that a cradle.

Comment: @Fred You should call that an answer.

Comment: Isnt cradle the clamp structure in a strongback? This looks more mobile @Fred

Comment: @suziVenus  I suppose that the "yellow fixture" you've specified could be called a cradle even if it is a part of a larger structure that is called something else. But that doesn't mean that it doesn't also have another, more specific name as well! However, if you're asking about the larger structure and not only the bits that are yellow, that may not have been clear from your original question, since "yellow" is in your title. We usually try to avoid major changes to a question after answers have been posted, if you think Fred's answer is not what you're looking for, comment further under it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The device the rocket is resting on is called a cradle.

Depending on the type of rocket, cradles are used in rocketry during construction, storage and transportation. They provide a stable platform that supports rockets during any of these phases. They reduce the likelihood of accidental movement, such as rolling during any of these phases.

The [caption](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rocket%20cradle&t=ffab&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fw-bindustries.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F03%2Fparts-holding-cradle-large-diameter-rocket-fuselage-WB-Industries-400x240.jpg) for the picture below is *Rocket fuselage parts holding cradle*.

[image]